# Find out when the recoll index was last updated

Tags: search, indexing, recoll

Is there a way to find out, when a [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/)-index was last updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it stores the indexes under `$HOME/.recoll/xapiandb` I would simply find the newest file under there:

```
find ~/.recoll/xapiandb -type f -printf '%T@\t%T+\n' \
| sort -nr | head -n 1 | cut -f2
```

This prints out all files with their epoch time and human-readable time, then sorts it so the newest is at the top and then prints only the human readable time of the first one. Adjust the `printf` format according to what output you need.